# Why aren't the start/end/lifetime entries in my external particle system cache being respected?

Tags: python, particles

I created a synthetic particle system cache using the following python code:

```
import csv
import gzip
import io
import struct

class BPhysWriter:
    # BPHYS_DATA_* from DNA_object_force.h
    column_words = (1,3,3,4,3,1,3,5)
    column_formats = ("i", "fff", "fff", "ffff", "fff", "f", "fff", "fffff")

    def __init__(self, f, flags):
        f.write(b"BPHYSICS")
        self.f = f
        self.count=0
        flavor=1
        f.write(struct.pack("iii", flavor, self.count, flags))

        self.format = ""
        for i in range(len(BPhysWriter.column_words)):
            if 0 != (flags & (1<<i)):
                self.format += BPhysWriter.column_formats[i]


    def store(self, *elements):
        i=self.count
        f = self.f
        self.count+=1
        f.seek(12)
        f.write(struct.pack("i", self.count))

        f.seek(0,2)
        f.write(struct.pack(self.format, *elements))

#
#
#

fpattern = "/var/tmp/blendcache_particles/bacon_%06d_00.bphys"

print(fpattern)
with gzip.GzipFile("hygdata_v3.csv.gz", "rb") as input,\
        open(fpattern%1, "wb") as out:
    phys = BPhysWriter(out, 3)
    r = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(input))
    count=0
    for row in r:
        mag = row[13]
        if mag == "mag":
            continue
        if float(mag)>6:
            continue
        x,y,z = map (float , row[17:20] )
        phys.store(count,x,y,z)
        count += 1

print(count)

with open(fpattern%0, "wb") as out:
    phys = BPhysWriter(out, 0x40)

    for i in range(count):
        phys.store(0,9999,9999)
```

If I stop there then it seems fine.  If I move (<kbd>G</kbd>) the object the particle system is attached to, then problems crop up.  Once I have altered the object, the particles seem to appear and die as I scrub the timeline.  This is despite the fact that the bacon_000000_00.bphys file specifies every particle starts at 0, ends at 9999 and lives 9999 frames.

How do I need to alter the cache file so that the particles live for the full time and stay in place?